# JWT authentication for near protocol in a python backend

Tags: nearprotocol

In ethereum, JWT authentication takes place with the following process:
https://github.com/Bearle/django-web3-auth/

1) Users sign a message in metamask using accounts private key.
2) account address and the signed message are POSTed to the backend
3) The backend verifies that the signature is correct and generates a signed Json Web Token (JWT) proving that the holder is in control of the address

Near protocol uses the following code to signing:

```
window.near = await nearlib.connect(Object.assign({ deps: { keyStore: new nearlib.keyStores.BrowserLocalStorageKeyStore() } }, window.nearConfig));

// Needed to access wallet login
window.walletAccount = new nearlib.WalletAccount(window.near);
```

And this:

```
await this.props.wallet.requestSignIn(
      window.nearConfig.contractName,
      appTitle
    )
```

How to use near login for backend, especially the verification step. In python in case of web3 it uses

```
from web3auth.utils import recover_to_addr

if not address == recover_to_addr(token, signature):
            return None
```

Can I use something in python (or javascript or rust) in the near protocol?   Rust example is fine as I can call the function in python through cffi.
Please provide some code.

Comment: An implementation : https://github.com/near/near-api-js/issues/342

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NEAR Wallet does not provide JWT authentication, but overall the procedure would be the following:

1. User signs a message with a key (e.g. after a sign in through Wallet or near-shell from terminal); `near-api-js` has [`signMessage`](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/25e7e60203965aee062ca19f352ff765859896ef/src/signer.ts#L28) method on Signer interface, but you can use any ed25519 implementation to sign a binary blob using the key
2. account id and the signed message are POSTed to the backend
3. The backend verifies that the signature is correct using any ed25519 library to check the signature correctness (again, [`near-api-js` KeyPair has `verify` method](https://github.com/near/near-api-js/blob/543b6fbe6998b0a52d9e6e9b2d13aa97370563ae/src/utils/key_pair.ts#L133)), and [query NEAR RPC API](https://docs.near.org/docs/interaction/rpc#view_access_key) to confirm that the key belongs to the account id.

Comment: Hi, trying to implement what you said, but not successful yet. Can you help in this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/62049349/1566713

Comment: Here is how I did in javascript: https://gist.github.com/sandoche/e5cdfd5af1e50e892e5a536b7c3d74bf